# Fetch vs Reset how to use it correctly with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have 4 Collections which should be filled with Data from the Server!

My json is a nested one :

`[ "data1":[...], "data2": [...], "data3": [...], "data4": [...] ]`

and i need a for every Collections a different data.

1. I started to use Fetch, but it fetched for every Collections the
   whole json before to choose the real needed data.
2. When i use reset some times Collections are filled with Data some
   times not!

   ```
   var pack = [];
   var Coll1 = new ClefsButtonsCollection();
   var Coll2 = new AccidentalsButtonsCollection();
   var Coll3 = new NotesButtonsCollection();
   var Coll4 = new RestsButtonsCollection();
   $.getJSON("/api/data.json", function(data){
       Coll1.reset( data.data1 );
       Coll2.reset( data.data2 );
       Coll3.reset( data.data3 );
       Coll4.reset( data.data4 );
   });
   pack.push( Coll1, Coll2, Coll3, Coll4 );
   ```

How can i filled my Collection before the Dom loaded? 
I use require.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. As you have to handle with the asynchronies nature of JavaScript you cant be sure that one callback was made before an other. The only way I see is to not call the api but render the JSON result directly in your html page, as described in [backbone FAQ](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap).